# Get computer names from a security group

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm trying to get the names of computers that I have added to a security group.
The searchbase is: `CN=Desktops,OU=Business,OU=Hosting,DC=AA,DC=BB,DC=com`.
I don't know if I should use `Get-ADComputer` or `Get-ADUser` or `Get-ADGroupMember`.
The computers are added like members of a security group.
How can I get the names of the computers?

Best Regards,
Dimo

Comment: From that question you're already most of the way to the answer. Have you actually tried the commands you're asking about? What results did you get from them?

Comment: Yes, I have tried, but I think I'm not using them right, because they output either an error or `$null`.

Comment: `Get-ADUser -Filter {name -like "LX1-*"} -SearchBase "CN=Desktops,OU=Business,OU=Hosting,DC=AA,DC=BB,DC=com"` This command returns `$null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I figure how to do it. Here is the solution:

```
get-adgroupmember -Identity "CN=Desktops,OU=Business,OU=Hosting,DC=AA,DC=BB,DC=com"
```

It wasn't working because I was using `-Partition` instead of `-Identity`.